# Moving element to the beginning of parent after animation

Tags: jquery

I have a simple succession of 5 images displayed in HTML. I have animated them so that they slowly move to the right (all at the same time).

When an image reaches the end of the screen, I want it to be pushed back to the beginning of its parent (a div tag).

In its current shape, this animation is pushing back the last image to the first image's position and it continuously swaps images since there is always one image out of the view space. Could you be so kind as to teach me what I've done wrong?

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="sliding-box">
  <img id="img1" src="http://jlwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/hd_wallpapers_a13.jpg">
  <img id="img2" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/wallpapers-hd-8000-8331-hd-wallpapers.jpg">
  <img id="img3" src="http://feelgrafix.com/data/wallpaper-hd/Wallpaper-HD-9.jpg">
  <img id="img4" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Fall-wallpaper-1366x768-HD-wallpaper.jpg">
  <img id="img5" src="http://www.wallpaperel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/HD-Wallpaper-Pictures-A71.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sliding-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

.sliding-box img {
    position: relative;
    height: 180px;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function checkPos() {
        $('.sliding-box').children().each(function() {
            if(isOffscreen(this)) {
                $(this).parent().prepend(this);
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(function() {
        $('.sliding-box').children().animate({left: '+=1'}, 1);
        checkPos();
    }, 1);
});

function isOffscreen(elem) {
    var off = $(elem).offset();
    var t = off.top;
    var l = off.left;
    var h = $(elem).height();
    var w = $(elem).width();
    var docH = $(window).height();
    var docW = $(window).width();

    return !(t > 0 && l > 0 && t + h < docH && l + w < docW);
}
```

And for your convenience, a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zya9hap3/).

(Please select JQuery 2.1.4 in the Javascript window, I am not sure why it's not saving it automatically)

**EDIT:** This must be done in JQuery, no other extension.

**EDIT2/ANSWER:** Manish Mishra's solution is correct, but I have some additions. Because of the *relative* positioning of each image, the animation would become stuttered and hasty as you can see in his [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zya9hap3/1/). My solution was to enforce *absolute* positioning to the images so that the space between them is ignored. All that remains is to figure out a way to position the images properly. Here's the updated css:

```
.sliding-box {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
}

.sliding-box img {
    position: absolute;
    height: 180px;
}

/* I know that the following is not pretty and can be probably done */
/* in a more elegant manner */

#img1 {

}

#img2 {
    left: 300px;
}

#img3 {
    left: 600px;
}

#img4 {
    left: 946px;
}

#img5 {
    left: 1280px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all, nice trick :). So you are doing everything right except few things :

1. So basically when you `prepend` the `img` element as soon as it touches the right boundary i.e. as soon as its `left` becomes equal to the width of container, you are not resetting its left (which has now been incremented to the right end of the container), so even though the element, in the flow, is now at the beginning of the container, it has a very high left, that's why your all elements keep shifting towards `right` out of the screen. So do this -

   in `checkPos`, inside the if condition simply add `$(this).css('left','10px');`
2. You need to get rid of the `setInterval` with interval `1ms`. You can use the `animate` complete callback to ensure repetition of the animation. Update your code like below (I've just taken out the function definitions out of `jQuery.ready` and instead of `setInterval`, have separated the animate logic in a separate function, to be able to call again:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {animate();});

   function checkPos() {

       $('.sliding-box').children().each(function() {

           if(isOffscreen(this)) {
              $(this).parent().prepend(this);
              $(this).css('left',10 +'px');
           }
      });
   };  

   function animate(){

       $('.sliding-box').children().animate({left: '+=1'}, 1, animate);
       checkPos();
   };

   function isOffscreen(elem) {

      var off = $(elem).offset();
      var t = off.top;
      var l = off.left;
      var h = $(elem).height();
      var w = $(elem).width();
      var docH = $(window).height();
      var docW = $(window).width();

      return !(t > 0 && l > 0 && t + h < docH && l + w < docW);
   }
   ```

   see this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zya9hap3/1/)

Comment: Hello, first of all I'd like to apologize for the late response, I have been away. I want to thank you for the solution, but one thing is missing: the animation should be as fluid as possible. Right now for some reason, when one image reaches the end, the animation is temporarily sped up and more than one element get quickly thrown into the left side (just like in the fiddle, and I've replicated this on my local). Do you have any idea why this happens? Thank you in advance ^^.

Comment: I have solved the issue. As I suspected initially, it was actually a CSS problem and not a JS one so fiddling with the JS didn't make it right. 

Practically the images had relative positioning, so the spaces between the images were kept the same at all times regardless. Absolute positioning made it right. I will add my CSS modifications to the question and I have marked your answer as the correct one. Thanks again mate!